# input equal to a string for one array, and get string from same position from another array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

So I have to array with strings:

```
var words = ['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'fe'];
var wordsLetters = ['a-b', 'b-c', 'c-d', 'f-e'];
```

words are listed in a  list. So when you click on one of the words it displays the word you click on in a b tag.

But I have struggled with trying to make an if statement that, that sees what word you have clicked on and displays that words letters. So if you click on ab, it displays ab and a-b.

I have made an if statement that can check what word you clicked on that displays the word and wordletter, but it only works with on word, so that means that I have to make 4 if statements, but I was wondering if you only had to make one statement?

```js
var words = ['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'fe'];
var wordsLetters = ['a-b', 'b-c', 'c-d', 'f-e'];


function getId() {
  var clickedId = event.srcElement.id;
  //console.log('word ID: ' + clickedId);
  var word = document.getElementById(clickedId).firstElementChild.innerHTML;

  document.getElementById('wordsPlaceholder').innerHTML = word;

  //if () {
  //
  //}
}
```

```css
li {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 5px 0px 5px -30px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="w1" onclick="getId()"><b>ab</b></li>
  <li id="w2" onclick="getId()"><b>bc</b></li>
  <li id="w3" onclick="getId()"><b>cd</b></li>
  <li id="w4" onclick="getId()"><b>de</b></li>
</ul>
<hr>
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <b>words: </b><u><b id="wordsPlaceholder"></b></u>
  <div style="display:block;"></div>
  <b>wordsLetters: </b></u><b id="wordsLettersPlaceholder"></b></u>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code snippet is not working.

Comment: @CodeManiac I know, it doesn't work when you click on the word it self. Click on the gray box.

Comment: Even on gray box it's throwing error. and the reason for this is event is undefined

Comment: @CodeManiac Weird it works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to  get the index and use it in the corresponding array.

I have also passed this into the click event so you do not get the error when clicking on the word itself.

One thing to note is that the [`b`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b) and [`u`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/u) tags have changed their semantic meaning in HTML5, if all you want is bold and underlined text then use css for this

```js
var words = ['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'fe'];
var wordsLetters = ['a-b', 'b-c', 'c-d', 'f-e'];


function getId(element) {
  var word = element.firstElementChild.innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('wordsPlaceholder').innerHTML = word;
  document.getElementById('wordsLettersPlaceholder').innerHTML = wordsLetters[words.indexOf(word)];
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="w1" onclick="getId(this)"><b>ab</b></li>
  <li id="w2" onclick="getId(this)"><b>bc</b></li>
  <li id="w3" onclick="getId(this)"><b>cd</b></li>
  <li id="w4" onclick="getId(this)"><b>de</b></li>
</ul>
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <b>words: </b><u><b id="wordsPlaceholder"></b></u>
  <div style="display:block;"></div>
  <b>wordsLetters: </b><u><b id="wordsLettersPlaceholder"></b></u>
</div>
```

Comment: When you click on the last one in the list, then I get undefined

Comment: @orc13a that's because the `wordsLetters` variable has `f-e` instead of `d-e` - thought that was intentional so you could see if the variable didn't exist - same with `words` (`fe` instead of `de`)

Comment: yeah I see, and thanks for the link to the meaning of indexOf and the response!

Answer (score 0):

You could take `indexOf` and seach for the index of the word, then take it as accessor for the wanted array.

```js
function getCorrespondingValue(string) {
    return wordsLetters[words.indexOf(string)];
}

var words = ['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'fe'],
    wordsLetters = ['a-b', 'b-c', 'c-d', 'f-e'];
    
console.log(getCorrespondingValue('bc'));
console.log(getCorrespondingValue('foo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Well if you format is always like this than i will suggest an alternative way.**

**Since you're having fixed words so i think will serve you the best.**

So the `split('')` will break the in single character and `join('-')` will add `-` between each character.

```js
function getCorrespondingValue(string) {
    return string.split('').join('-');
}

    
console.log(getCorrespondingValue('bc'));
console.log(getCorrespondingValue('ab'));
```